# Configuring Hazelcast via Spring Boot application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hazelcast

I was able to get Hazelcast caching working in my Spring Boot application with a hazelcast.xml file. However, the application has multiple profiles and I'm trying to avoid managing multiple hazelcast.xml files. I want to configure all of the options within the application.yml. If I understand [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-hazelcast.html) correctly, I should be able to do the following in my application.yml, correct?

```
hazelcast:
  client:
    config:
      network:
        join:
          tcp-ip:
            member:
              - 1.2.3.4
              - 9.8.7.6
      map:
        name: user-details
        max-size: 1000
        eviction-policy: LRU
        eviction-percentage: 10
        time-to-live-seconds: 900
```

Except it's not working. I've tried finding other references to configuring Hazelcast through the application.yml but have found none. Is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `application.yml` file is a way to pass configuration properties to Spring Boot. At the moment, there isn't an automatic way to pass these from one to the other.

So what you're trying to do won't work as is. Perhaps this is worth you logging an issue on https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast or https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot for it to be addressed.

In the meantime, if you have an `application.yml` with a property such as

```
hazelcast:
 group:
  name: "stack.overflow"
```

then this will be put into Spring's environment as `hazelcast.group.name` property.

And you had a `hazelcast.xml` containing

```
<group>
    <name>${hazelcast.group.name}</name>
</group>
```

then "*all*" you'd need then to do is have your code create a `Config` @Bean like this

```
@Bean
public Config config(Environment environment) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("hazelcast.group.name", environment.getProperty("hazelcast.group.name"));
    return new ClasspathXmlConfig("hazelcast.xml", props);
}
```

to pass the property from the YML file into the XML file.

Comment: Let me know if you need more info to get it going. The bottom line here is it's more effort than anything should be with Spring.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it looks like the auto configuration is picking up the hazelcast.xml from the classpath before the config bean runs? It's saying "Could not find a value for property 'hazelcast.group' on node: null". I've confirmed that the property is present in my application-local.yml and that I am running the local profile.

Comment: Never mind, I got it. Had to put the @Bean in my top level configuration class. Seems to be working now, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same issue and added a configuration class for this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HazelcastConfig::class)
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "hazelcast", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@Primary
class HazelcastConfig: Config()
```

And then I just put this in the application.yml:

```
hazelcast:
  group_config:
    name: hazelcast-cluster
    password: hazelcast-cluster
  network_config:
    join:
      multicast_config:
        enabled: false
      kubernetes_config:
        enabled: false
```

(Yes I know it is an old question but it is the most popular according to Google)

Comment: Nice trick although [it will not support autocompletion of the nested fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62789223/how-to-ask-spring-boot-configuration-processor-to-handle-nested-class-in-a-subcl)