# how to ask spring-boot-configuration-processor to handle nested class in a subclass of a Configuration Class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a project called FooBar, there is no Spring in this project. There is a configuration class `FoorBarConfiguration`.

```java
import another.package.ServerProperties;
public class FooBarProperties {
    
    private Long id;
    private String description;
    private ServerProperties serverProperties;
    
    //getter and setter
}
```

The `ServerProperties` is not a nested class in `FooBarProperties`

```java
public class ServerProperties {

    private String host;
    private int port;

    //getter and setter
}
```

Then I want to write a spring-boot-stater project for the FooBar project. At the same time, I hope to configure `ServerProperties` through `application.properties` and spring-boot-configuration-processor can help me to generate a sufficient `spring-configuration-metadata.json` which will prompt properties in `ServerProperties`. For example, when I type in `com.example.server-properties.`, it will prompt to type in `port` or `host`.

A crude approach is to copy the `FoobarProperties.java` into the starter project.But this is too rude. And I noticed such usage:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.example")
public class AutoFooBarProperties extends FooBarProperties {
}
```

but it seems that spring-boot-configuration-processor won't do anything for this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hmm. That _should_ work. However, it's more conventional to put your properties in a POJO named `FooBarProperties` and not mix it with configuration classes. I also suggest trying not using a subclass and seeing if that helps.

Comment: `@NestedConfigurationProperty` should be used to indicate that a property is a nested namespace. I am not entirely sure I understood your problem though.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll could you please tell me what is the confusing part in my expression?emmm..simply, I have a project without any spring and I want to write a spring-boot-starter for it. At the same time I want to reuse the property class, but the property class is uanble to be annotated by any spring annotation since there is no any spring in origin project.. then how do I use spring-boot-configuration-processor on it within the starter project? Thanks.

Comment: You can't I am afraid. Asking the processor to handle `ServerProperties` as a nested  class need a flag on the field.